# Unable to use data annotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

So here we are trying to get a handle on EF7 ahead of the game and I'm running into what I can only call madness.

In EF6 I use annotations quite a bit and I am trying to carry that over into EF7 which according to the UnicornStore project this is totally valid, however I'm running into a problem wherein visual studio 2015 complains that I don't have a reference to the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations assembly. Fair enough, I add my reference to the assembly and now I get the following from DNX Core 5.0:

```
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'DataAnnotations' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?) Lib.DNX Core 5.0
```

For the life of me I can't figure this out as to whats going on here, as when I look at the UnicornStore as my reference there's no reference to that assembly in the project.json, however there is a reference in the project.lock.json and as I understand it you're not supposed to edit that file.

The big question what am I doing wrong? Why would DNX 4.5.x not complain about the reference and yet DNX Core 5.0 is?

Comment: Do you have `System.ComponentModel` .dll reference in your project.

Comment: Yes, the  reference is there, but dmx core complains that its not there

Comment: Not sure but try cleaning your solution and then set the property of `System.ComponentModel` Dll to Copy Local = True.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .Net 4.6(also called vNext) web project has a dependency on `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`. This pulls in a big tree of dependencies, the data annotations are under the package `Microsoft.DataAnnotations`

for using Data annotation in your project use `Microsoft.DataAnnotations` in place of `System.ComponantModel.DataAnnotations`.

Comment: Gah! Bloody hell, three days wasted only to learn that microsoft is juggling everything around. This is exactly what I needed! Thanks Vikas,

Comment: `Microsoft.DataAnnotations` was removed in beta4. You should be using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` on .NET Framework and `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` on .NET Core.

Comment: And now it's 1.0 rtm days and this is all wrong again.

Comment: For .Net Core 1.0, you need to install the System.ComponentModel.Annotations Nuget package and then use the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace. 

Clarification for those like me that got hung up a different namespace for longer that I'd like to admit.

Answer (score 9):

I just had precisely this problem with beta8. I resolved it by combining the other answers and comments given here so as to provide cross-compilation for both DNX 4.5.1 and DNX Core 5.0:

```js
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": {
    "frameworkAssemblies": {
      "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations": "4.0.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
    }
  },
  "dnxcore50": {
    "dependencies": {
      "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.0.11-beta-23409"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations": "4.0.0.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
      }
    }
  }
```