# Unable to use data annotations in .net core 1.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, data-annotations, .net-core

Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30472879/unable-to-use-data-annotations) from the early beta (dnx) days, I am trying to port code to .net core 1.0 rtm, and the code replies on the following unit which contains things like the ValidationAttribute type and other stuff:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Hl7.Fhir.Introspection
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class FhirElementAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    ...
```

How do I port such code to dotnet core 1.0 rtm?

Comment: Some early beta days suggest unit name changed to System.ComponentModel.Annotations, but that's not working.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/4.1.0-rc2-24027)?

Comment: Oh, that's pre-release Bits but not a dotnet-RC2-level bits

Comment: Whooops... my fault :) [This one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/) should be the one you're looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the unofficial [Reverse Package Search](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=AttributeUsage) to search for classes inside new Microsoft open-sourced packages.

You are looking for the `System.Runtime.AttributeUsageAttribute` inside [System.Runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime) Package. It's available for `.NET Standard 1.0` and up.

EDIT:
Sorry. You were asking about `ValidationAttribute`, not `AttributeUsage`, my bad. The reverse package [search](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=ValidationAttribute) points to [System.ComponentModel.Annotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/),

Comment: Thank you.  Saved me a lot of time.